# Put folder name in subfolder name in filename

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to also put the folder name in a filename. Like this:

```
Folder1\SubFolder1

FileName1.abc

Filename2.abc

Subfolder2

Filename1.abc

filename2.abc
```

Result:

```
-Folder1_SubFolder1_Filename1.abc

-Folder1_SubFolder1_Filename2.abc

-Folder2_SubFolder1_Filename1.abc

-Folder2_SubFolder1_Filename2.abc
```

With this code I only get the subdir in the Filename.

```
get-childitem -Path 'D:\Temp' -recurse | Where-Object {$.Psiscontainer -eq $false} | Rename-Item -NewName {$.Directory.Name + "" + $.Name}
```

Please let me know.

Comment: the fileinfo object has a `.FullName` property that has the full path in it. you can trim away the drive letter [or UNC] info and then replace the path delimiters with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

the `Directory` property also has a `Parent` property. You can use that like so:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Temp' -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Parent, $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name -join '_' }
```

This command simply gets all Files in a folder and it's subfolders, then proceeds to rename the files to the parent directory name, the directory name and the file name and joins them together with `_`

Comment: Thank you, that did the job